# convert a structured string into array

Tags: javascript

this question might have been asked already. But i really have no idea what to search for.

If I have a string like

```
{{aa:bb,aaa:bbb,cc:ee{{aa:cd,cdc:dd,{{ss:ee}},kk:ee}},se:ff}}
```

I need to get output in probably in array

ar[0] = aa:bb, ar[1]=aaa:bbb, ar[3] = {{...}}

I tried using `variable.split("}}")`

which is breaking the string and not getting the actual data.

Is there any recursive function to do this? 
I am not able to search because I have no clear idea of what objects,strings.

Comment: You're going to have to figure out exactly how your string should be mapped to some data structure, and then you'll have to write a parser to do the conversion.

Comment: You'll have to either do what Pointy says, or what I would recommend is that you use JSON and use the built-in `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you used an existing format for structuring your string, such as JSON:

```
["aa:bb","aaa:bbb","cc:ee",["aa:cd","cdc:dd",["ss:ee"],"kk:ee"],"se:ff"]
```

Then you could just run it through `JSON.parse()`. - It'd be far easier than trying to decode the meaning of that string without being told what it means.

Comment: You can always convert the custom format to JSON via regexes.

Comment: Which would be a real pain in the backside and probably much harder than just changing the string format where it's produced. What does the `cc:ee{{aa:cd...` part mean anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to parse a JSON string into an object. I'm not certain, but at least it looks like that based on the format of your string. Can you confirm if the source is providing JSON output?

If yes:

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) other SO question.

Comment: Sorry, I was just adding some comments on that.